# Remove comma from javascript array

Tags: javascript

Hi all I am framing a url with Query string in javascript as follows every thing works fine but a comm is coming in between the query string so can some one help me

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RedirectLocation() {
        var cntrl = "Q1;Q2";
        var str_array = cntrl.split(';');
        var cnt = str_array.length;
        if (cnt == 0) {
            location.href = '/callBack.aspx';
        }
        else {
            var arr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
                str_array[i] = str_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
                arr.push(str_array[i] + '=1');
                if (i != str_array.length - 1) {
                    arr.push('&');
                }
            }
            location.href = '/Sample.aspx?' + arr;
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is giving me the query string as follows `Sample.aspx?Q1=1,&,Q2=1` I need this to be like `` `Sample.aspx?Q1=1&Q2=1 ``

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove the commas from a string you could simply do

```
s = s.replace(/,/g,'');
```

But in your specific case, what you want is not to add the commas. Change

```
location.href = '/Sample.aspx?' + arr;
```

to

```
location.href = '/Sample.aspx?' + arr.join('');
```

What happens is that adding an array to a string calls `toString` on that array and that function adds the commas :

`""+["a","b"]`  gives `"a,b"`

Answer (score 4):

Don't rely on the implicit string conversion (which concatenates the array elements with a comma as separator), explicitly [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array elements with `&`:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < str_array.length; i++) {
    str_array[i] = str_array[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, "");
    arr.push(str_array[i] + '=1');
}
location.href = '/Sample.aspx?' + arr.join('&');
```

Think about it like this: You have a set of `name=value` entries which you want to have separated by `&`.

Comment: +1 I didn't check your code (I trust you enough) but pushing the '&' in the array isn't the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arr.join(glue)` to concatenate Array elements with something inbetween. In your case glue would be an empty string `arr.join("")`.